# Laravel Blade: Show meta-tag only when variable is given on extend

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is the beginning of my `master.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <meta name="description" content="@yield('meta_desc')">
```

If I extend this to a page where no `meta_desc` is given like this:

```
@extends('layouts.index')

@section('title')
A nice title
@endsection
```

The this page has in the header a meta-tag with an empty description

```
<meta name="description" content="">
```

However I would like to skip the meta-tag completely, when no meta_desc is given. I tried to change the code in the `master.blade.php` to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>@yield('title', )</title>
    @if(!empty($meta_desc))
    <meta name="description" content="@yield('meta_desc')">
    @endif
```

but then the meta-tag

```
<meta name="description" content="">
```

would be always be missing then. How can I fix it?

Comment: keep the <meta> in the master.blade and then when route is created pass the $meta_desc as a variable and then do the if check in the view..

Comment: @DhavalChheda sorry but could you explain that a bit further? Isn't that exactly what I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    @if($metaDesc != "")
       <meta name="description" content="{{ $metaDesc }}">
    @endif
```

Controller

```
$metaDesc = "Testing";
        return view('test', compact('metaDesc'));
```

test.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Testing')

@section('content')
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur consectetur eligendi esse id praesentium ullam! Alias asperiores, consectetur delectus, dicta facilis impedit itaque iure magni nisi odio perferendis tenetur ut!
@endsection
```

so basically what i've done is passed the meta description variable to the master layout and there if the variable is "" then we don't show the `<meta>` at all..

Feel free to reach out if any doubts..

Comment: Thank you! I tested it and it works even if I do not pass `metaDesc` in the `extends` function (i.e. just `@extends('layouts.master')` seems to work). Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome Adam .. I did not know I could omit that variable in extends.. Thanks for that